# How to this function update automatically when I add a new sheet update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found it :

```
function GetAllSheetNames() {
var out = new Array()
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
return out 
}
```

How does it change when I create a new sheet? Currently I have to `= GetAllSheetNames ()` to be updated. thanks.

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Where do you need this output and in what format? What do you mean by 'automatically'?

Comment: Thank you for asking. For example I have a spreadsheet of 2 sheets A, B. And I go to cell A1 and enter "= GetAllSheetName ()" it will return A and B. I want if I create  C, D. in cell A1 will change the result to A, B, C, D. sorry if I write too long, I just learn.  I found onEdit (), onChange () but don't know how to use it.

Comment: custom functions are not updated automatically like the regular google sheets ones. Only if an argument they use changes.

Comment: Is there a way to always get cell A1 to get all the sheet names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You need to use the installable trigger `onChange` and it should not be used as a custom function.

At the moment you want the custom function to update automatically. Unfortunately this is not the behavior of custom functions by design. So that method will not work. However, you can adapt your code to pure Apps Script, only you have to make sure to specify where you want the value to be placed. Its not like formula where you place the formula in the cell you want the value, but with Apps Script you will need to say "place the value in A1" for example.

#### Current behavior

[image]

When I ran the custom function you posted, it gave this result.

#### Modifications

To adapt your code to a `onChange` trigger, I changed it to the below (I also added code comments to explain the code if you are interested):

```js
function updateSheetNames() {
  // Initialize Spreadsheet file
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  // Put all sheets in array
  var sheets = file.getSheets()

  // Create new array to hold sheet names
  var out = new Array()

  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++){
    var sheetName = sheets[i].getName()
    out.push( [ sheetName ] )
  }
  
  // Identify target sheet to place sheet names
  var targetSheet = sheets[0]
  // Identify target range to place sheet names
  // This selects row 1, column 1 to however many rows are in out and 1 column.
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,out.length,1)

  // This range is to clear the list of existing ranges,
  // because if you delete, then you may have a left over sheet name
  // at the moment it is set to clear 50 rows, but change 50 to however many
  // number of sheets you think will be the maximum
  var rangeToClear = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,50,1)
  rangeToClear.clearContent()

  // Finally set the values of the range to the sheet names
  targetRange.setValues(out)
}
```

#### Installing the trigger

Once you have this code you will need to *install* the trigger, as `onChange` needs to be installed (not like `onEdit`).

Press this button on the script editor

[image]

Then:

[image]

With these settings:

[image]

Then this should work in the way that you have described.

#### References and Further Reading

- [onChange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onChange())
- [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger)
- [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/editors/sheets#custom_functions)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

Comment: Yeah! that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks you so much. and how to return the result always in a specific Sheet, like cell A1 of "SheetZ": D

Comment: A pleasure! To have it always with specific sheet change this line `var targetSheet = sheets[0]` to `var targetSheet = file.getSheetByName('SheetZ')`

Comment: Sorry, you can help me again. I have a worksheet like the above, and this time I need in cell A1 (or any cell) to display the name of that Sheet (as for SheetZ  cell A1 ```SheetZ``` or Sheet123 and cell  A1 is ```Sheet123``` and the remaining cells are not deleted). And I will Add Trigger OnChange again. thank you hi.

Comment: Hi Leti, I would like to help, but since your new question is a bit complicated to edit into my original answer and too long to fit in a comment, I would ask you please to ask a new question. Usually the best thing is to close this question by accepting the answer you like best and then asking a new question (you can ask many questions in one day!). This keeps the site cleaner and easier for new people to find the answers they are looking for. Thank you. [How to ask follow up questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: oh sorry i didn't know this will affect, i will create another question. hope to see you again: d

Comment: hi. Can you help me please :d https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67123212/how-the-cell-locks-automatically-after-checkbox-is-true-google-apps-script/67123688#67123688

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is:

```
function onChange(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // or use getSheetByName('NAME_OF_SHEET') to specify
  var cell = sheet.getRange('A1');

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var out = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){
    out.push(sheets[i].getName()); //use this line of you'd like all sheet names in one cell, separated by a comma
    out.push([sheets[i].getName()]); //use this line of you'd like all sheet names in cells below each other
  }
  cell.setValue(out);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried, but it reported "TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.GetActiveSpreadsheet is not a function". I don't know where I did it wrong.

Comment: Apologies, my mistake with a couple of typos there, it's now corrected.

Comment: Dont know why it still not work for me, but i think i already found answer. Thank you,  Andras Sztrokay. :D

Comment: Just make sure you delete one of the lines that start with "out.push" according to what format you'd need (see the comments starting with // at the end of thost lines). But of course if you've already got a solution, that's great.

Comment: Aw, sorry. It working very well . Thanks :))

Comment: Great, thanks for letting me know. If you're happy with the answer, please vote it up / accept it. Thanks!